# Computed not updating the properties in my child

Tags: vue.js, graphql

very very new to vue3 for my new job.

I'm having the next issue:

1. I'm doing an API call with useQuery to get data from my backend.
2. Then, with computed, first checking if the data is already here and returning an empty object
3. after that, my child object is never receiveing the updated user when the query is done.

here is the code

```
// parent component
<template>
  <div class="card shadow-xl card-bordered">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted">
        <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_1" role="tab" class="tab" :aria-label="$t('settings.userPreferences.userPreferences')" checked/>
        <UserPreferences :user="user" />

        <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_1" role="tab" class="tab" :aria-label="$t('settings.devices.devices')" />
<!--        <Devices />-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import UserPreferences from "../components/UserPreferences.vue";
import { GET_CURRENT_USER } from "../graphql";
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { User } from "@/gql/graphql";
import {UseQueryReturn} from "@vue/apollo-composable/dist/useQuery";

const { result: currentUser, loading: currentUserLoading }: UseQueryReturn<{ user: User }, null> = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER, null, {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
});
const user = computed(() => {
  if (!currentUser?.value?.user) return { name: '', email: '', preferredLanguage: '', defaultDeviceLanguage: '' }

  const { user } = currentUser.value
  const name = `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`

  return {
    ...user,
    name,
  }
})

</script>

<style scoped>
[type='radio']:focus {
  --tw-ring-color: transparent;
}

</style>
```

And the child

```
//child compnent

<template>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content">
    <div class="grid grid-rows-1 justify-items-center">
      <div class="flex justify-center flex-column py-10">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
          <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
            <div class="label">
              <span class="label-text">{{ $t('settings.userPreferences.languages.deviceUserLanguage') }}</span>
            </div>
            <select class="select select-bordered" v-model="newUserLanguage">
              <option v-for="(value, key) in displayedLanguages" :key="key" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <label class="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
            <div class="label">
              <span class="label-text">{{ $t('settings.userPreferences.languages.deviceDefaultLanguage') }}</span>
            </div>
            <select class="select select-bordered" v-model="newDeviceLanguage">
              <option v-for="(value, key) in displayedDeviceLanguages" :key="key" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="SaveEdit" :disabled="!userDataChanged"> Save </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {computed, ComputedRef, onMounted, ref} from "vue";
  import { User } from "@/gql/graphql";
import {UPDATE_USER_DEFAULT_DEVICE_LANGUAGE, UPDATE_USER_PREFERRED_LANGUAGE} from "@/modules/settings/graphql";

  import useNotifications from '@/composables/useNotifications.js';
  import i18n from '@/i18n';
import {useMutation} from "@vue/apollo-composable";
  const { t } = i18n.global
  const { notify } = useNotifications();
  const { user } = defineProps<{
    user: User
  }>();

  const displayedLanguages: Record<string, string> = {
    en: t('settings.userPreferences.languages.english'),
    es: t('settings.userPreferences.languages.spanish'),
  }

  const displayedDeviceLanguages: Record<string, string> = {
    en: t('exam.setup.languages.en'),
    es: t('exam.setup.languages.es'),
    fr: t('exam.setup.languages.fr'),
    pt: t('exam.setup.languages.pt'),
    cpf: t('exam.setup.languages.cpf'),
    ru: t('exam.setup.languages.ru'),
    ar: t('exam.setup.languages.ar'),
    vi: t('exam.setup.languages.vi'),
    ko: t('exam.setup.languages.ko'),
    zh: t('exam.setup.languages.zh'),
    zhs: t('exam.setup.languages.zhs'),
  }
  type LocalLanguage = 'en' | 'es'
  const updatedUser = ref({ ...Object.assign({}, user) })

  console.log("1")
  console.log(user)
  const newDeviceLanguage = ref(user.defaultDeviceLanguage);
  const newUserLanguage = ref(user.preferredLanguage);
  const userDataChanged = true;
  console.log(newDeviceLanguage)
  console.log(newUserLanguage)
  const preferredLanguage = user.preferredLanguage ? displayedLanguages[user.preferredLanguage] : ''
  const defaultDeviceLanguage = user.defaultDeviceLanguage ? displayedDeviceLanguages[user.defaultDeviceLanguage] : ''



</script>
```

I wish I explain my self in a way you understand me..
I don't really know if the thing is in computed or in the child component

NEW UPDATE:
With vue tools i can see that the actual value of user inside the child component is the user from the api but for example if I click in SaveEdit button it will show the empty one on console
Thanks!

Comment: You lose reactivity here `const { user } = defineProps`. Stick to using props.user everywhere

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought was fixed in 3.3? https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#reactive-props-destructure

Comment: OP What version of vue are you using?

Comment: "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.9.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"

Comment: The prop is ok for 3.3 as noted above. Please, provide enough details for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no SaveEdit. The next places to check are the ones where "user" is used. Here the initial value is accessed once `ref({ ...Object.assign({}, user) })`. You need to update these refs in a watcher when "user" is changed, which can result in poor UX for a form, or just don't render it until user data is fetched

Answer (score 1):

I Hope I got your problem well:

```
const newDeviceLanguage = ref(user.defaultDeviceLanguage);
const newUserLanguage = ref(user.preferredLanguage);
```

This data will not be change reactively by changed props.
**They occur at the time of setup**. How it works => we receive the data, write it to these variables, and that's it, make them reactive but they will not be updated after the user changes.

**A few solutions how to fix this**:

```
const newDeviceLanguage = computed(()=> props.user?.defaultDeviceLanguage))
const newUserLanguage = computed(()=> props.user?.user.preferredLanguage)))
```

or

```
const newDeviceLanguage = ref(user.defaultDeviceLanguage);
const newUserLanguage = ref(user.preferredLanguage);

watch(()=> props.user, (_newUser)=> {
    newDeviceLanguage.value = _newUser.defaultDeviceLanguage
    newUserLanguage.value = _newUser.preferredLanguage
}, 
{
    deep: true,
})
```